# How can you prove $\binom {2n}{2} = 2\binom{n}{2} + n^2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Is there a way one can prove that this is true: ${2n \choose 2} = 2{n\choose 2} + n^2$ ?

I am thinking it may involve binomial theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by 2(n, 2)?

Comment: One can use the fact that $\binom{k}{2}=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$. Or else one can use a combinatorial argument. There are other ways. I assume you meant $2C(n,2)$.

Comment: "I am thinking it may involve binomial theorem." If you mean that this "may involve" the **definition** of the binomial coefficients, indeed it does. What is the definition of ${k\choose 2}$, already?

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\binom{2n}{2}&=\frac{(2n)!}{2!(2n-2)!}\\\\
&=n(2n-1) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
2\binom{n}{2}+n^2&=2\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}\\\\
&=n(n-1)+n^2\\\\
&=n(2n-1) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Upon comparing the right-hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ we obtain the result!

Answer (score 3):

Combinatorial method: consider the following diagram.

[image: diagram]

The number of lattice points in the big square, such that the first coordinate is strictly less than the second, is equal to those in the top-left little square, plus the two little triangles.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we wish to select two people from a group of $n$ men and $n$ women.  Then $\binom{2n}{2}$ is the number of ways we can select two people from the group.  Alternatively, we can select two men in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways, two women in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways, and one man and one woman in $n \cdot n = n^2$ ways.  Hence, $$\binom{2n}{2} = \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{2} + n \cdot n = 2\binom{n}{2} + n^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Induction is fine, too. We have: $$\binom{a}{2}=\binom{a-1}{2}+\binom{a-1}{1},$$ hence we just need to check that the given identity holds for $n=1$ and that $n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have collection of $n$ red and $n$ black balls. In how many ways we can choose 2 balls form this set?
First solution: ${2n}\choose{2}$.

Second solution: we can choose two red or two black balls in $2 {{n}\choose{2}}$ ways and a pair of one red and one black ball in $n \cdot n = n^2$ ways.

Hence ${{2n}\choose{2}} = 2 {{n}\choose {2}} + n^2$.

Comment: This is essentially N. F. Taussig's answer

Comment: … which is itself essentially mine cast into words :)

Comment: I wrote my answer slower... I think