# On the proof that $\binom{2n}{2}=2\binom{n}{2}+n^{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof, combinatorial-proofs

I came across this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1456022/751970) and this [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2658569/751970) while browsing through the combinatorics section.
Although both of them have been closed, I find the discussion inside the solutions inside the posts quite interesting and wish to reinitiate the discussion and seek for alternative solutions if any.

**Problem Statement**

Both authors wished to prove the following:

$$
\binom{2n}{2}=2\cdot\binom{n}{2}+n^{2}
$$

**Sample Solution from The Posts**

User N.F. Taussig argued that if one wishes to select $2$ people out of $n$ men and $n$ women, one can:

- Directly select two out of everyone in $\binom{2n}{2}$ ways, or
- Select two out of all men, two out of all women, or one of each in $\binom{n}{2}$, $\binom{n}{2}$, $n^{2}$ ways respectively and $2\cdot\binom{n}{2}+n^{2}$ in total

In conclusion, both LHS and RHS count the same object and must be equal.

In a separate answer, Graham Kemp suggest to find a counting argument for $\binom{2n}{2}=\binom{2}{1}\binom{n}{2}+n^{2}$

**My Solution**

Through simple modification to the RHS, the problem seems to be much easier:

$$
\binom{2n}{2}=\binom{n}{2}\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{0}\binom{n}{2}
$$

One can immediately notice that this is nothing but the Vandermonde's identity. In this form, Taussig's combinatorial argument also become really obvious.

**Remark**

I find it interesting because two of the most basic expressions in combinatorics i.e. $\binom{n}{0}=1$ and $\binom{n}{1}=n$ can make such combinatoric problem trivial. I also with to know if there are other alternative solutions.

Comment: Presumably you don't want direct application of algebra, such as $\binom{2n}{2}=\frac{2n(2n-1)}{2}=\frac{2n(n+(n-1))}{2}=\frac{2n^2}{2}+\frac{2n(n-1)}{2}=n^2+2\binom{n}{2}$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop any kind of solutions are welcomed. The purpose of this post is to gather as many alternative solutions as possible, as well as for my own documentation

Comment: I downvoted because to me, this post doesn't really add anything valuable to the site, as this question has been asked a gazillion times here, [as a quick Approach0 search would show.](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cbinom%7B2n%7D%7B2%7D%20%3D%202%5Ccdot%5Cbinom%20n2%20%2Bn%5E2%24&p=1)

Comment: @insipidintegrator that's fair enough, although I wish to keep the post to see if there is any new solution out there

Comment: One can also write $$(1+x)^{2n}=\big((1+x)^n\big)^2$$ and identify the coefficients of order $2$.

Answer (score 7):

You can define a function $$f(n) = {2n\choose 2} -2{n\choose 2}-n^2$$

Clearly it is a polynomial of a degree 2, so in other to prove $f(n)=0$ for all $n$ it is enough to prove for $3$ natural numbers, say $n=1,2,3$ and you are done.

Comment: That's a great solution. I didn't think of using polynomial properties to solve a combinatorics problem